# Is it possible to align text horizontally on a character?

Tags: css, text, alignment

Say I have a piece of text like this:

```
x = 2 / y
a + b + c = x
```

Is it possible via CSS (or perhaps other tricks) to align those lines so they end up looking like this?

```
        x = 2 / y
a + b + c = x
```

I suppose I could stick the left part in one table column, the = sign in the next and the right side in the third and then use right align, center and left align, but that doesn't feel particularly clean or semantically correct :p

Comment: Wouldn't aligning them both right work for that?

Comment: I think he wants to align by the equals sign, and no, not every equation leaves the right-hand side with a single digit or character.

Comment: Exactly. I'll tweak the example to be more clear :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `text-align` CSS property to align the text.
If you want to align according to the number of spaces in your text, use `white-space` to preserve spaces, in conjunction with a monospace font, **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cCLZy/**

```
<style>
.right-align {
    /*text-align: right;*/
     white-space: pre; 
     font-family: monospace;
}
</style>

<!-- Spaces and newlines are preserved -->
<div class="right-align">
        x = 2
a + b + c = x
</div>
```

Comment: Of course, but then you'd need to align those with spaces first, which could be annoying. Point of this question was kind of to avoid having to do that :)

Comment: Actually most server side languages provide constructs to reserve and use up spaces etc, if you compute/store these calculations server side it might be a little but more efficient to figure out the spacings server side. Shouldn't be hard either way.

Comment: this assumes a monospace font

Answer (score 0):

You always put the text in a table. Would allow you to align everything.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit strict, but I hope this helps.

The trick is in `display: table-cell` property, and to give the `<span>` tags a "fixed" width.

For example, I gave `<span>` tags a `width:6em`, which works for shorter sentences, like the snippet below, or fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7RgcY/1/).

```css
body{ font-family:consolas, courier, monospaced }
div>span:nth-of-type(1){ text-align:right }
div>span:nth-of-type(3){ text-align:left }
div>span.equal:after{ content:'=' }
div>span{ display:table-cell; width:6em }
div>span.equal{ background:pink; width:1em; padding-left:0.5em }
```

```html
<div>
  <span>x</span>
  <span class="equal"></span>
  <span> 2 / y</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>a + b + c</span>
  <span class="equal"></span>
  <span>x</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>x + y</span>
  <span class="equal"></span>
  <span>a + b + c</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I would use a table to do ad-hoc alignments like this.

But in the specific case of aligning math equations, things could be much easier with a tool made for rendering maths, like LaTeX. Aligning equations in LaTeX is very simple and flexible. To add LaTeX to browser, you can use JS libraries like MathJax or KATEX.

Answer (score -1):

`text-align:right` ??

http://jsfiddle.net/Q42U4/

Comment: Would've worked with my too simple example. Updated it now to bring forth more what I meant :)

Answer (score -1):

I didn´t test this aproach, it may need some tweaking but it has to work. If you want to align the equal signs you could do this:

```
<style>
.left {
width: x; /*You have to give them width to make the effect of two columns*/
text-align: right;
float: left;
}
.right {
width: x; /*You have to give them width to make the effect of two columns*/
text-align: left;
float: left;
}
.clr { clear: both; } /*Clear to keep next elements from floating too*/
</style>
<div class="left">
 <p>x = <br />
 a + b + c =</p>
</div>
<div class="right">
 <p>2 / y<br />
 x</p>
</div>
<div class="clr"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, updated the example to make it clearer why it isn't as simple as right-aligning, hehe.